# I am trying to show an AlertDialog when a ListView item is clicked within the Adapter class, but a black screen is covering the dialog

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have an adapter class that is loading an ArrayList of items into a ListView. It does this fine. I am also trying to create an AlertDialog popup of an item in the ListView whenever a hyperlinked text is clicked in a ListView item, referencing a specific ListView item. However, when I show the AlertDialog the dialog has a black screen on top of it covering everything.

From what I've read so far on other posts the issue is possibly being caused because the ListView item is already inflated in the ListView and I'm trying to reinflate it in the AlertDialog. If that is the issue then, then how can I get a reference to the already inflated ListView item, show it in the AlertDialog, all from the adapter class.

Here's a picture of what's happening.

[image]

Here's the following code for my adapter class we well.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_reply, null);

    TextView textView_name = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    TextView textView_time = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    TextView textView_title = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.textViewThreadTitle);

    textView_name.setText(this.reply_list.get(position).getName());
    textView_time.setText(this.reply_list.get(position).getTime_diff() + " ago");
    textView_title.setText(Html.fromHtml(reply_list.get(position).getTitle()));

    Spannable clickableMessage = (Spannable) textView_message.getText();
    clickableMessage = Find_String_Matches(clickableMessage);
    textView_message.setText(clickableMessage, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

    return listView;
}

private Spannable Find_String_Matches(Spannable text){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(thread_regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text.toString());

    while (matcher.find()) {
        Log.d("start", "Start index: " + matcher.start());
        Log.d("end", " End index: " + matcher.end());
        Log.d("found", " Found: " + matcher.group());

        text = addClickablePart(text, matcher.start(), matcher.end());
    }

    return text;
};

public void Popup_Thread(final int pos){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View listReplyView = getView(pos, null, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(listReplyView);

    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
};
```

Comment: you want to inflate item layout in your dialog box?

Comment: Yes, it's already inflated in my ListView. I want take the ListView item as is and show it in my AlertDialog. That's why I am recalling the GetView method of the adapter class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. There is no need to inflate the layout

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setMessage("Your message");
                View listReplyView = getView(pos, null, null);
                dialogBuilder.setView(listReplyView);
                // Yes option
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.positive_option,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                              //smth
                            }
                        });

                // Cancel option
                builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.negative_option,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss(); // If cancel is pressed, dialog is closed
                            }
                        });

                // Show the dialog window
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to inflate your layout item :

```
public void Popup_Thread(final int pos){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout. list_item_reply, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

// set value into textview
TextView textView_name = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
TextView textView_time = (TextView) 
dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
TextView textView_title = (TextView) 
dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textViewThreadTitle);

textView_name.setText(this.reply_list.get(pos).getName());
textView_time.setText(this.reply_list.get(pos).getTime_diff() + " ago");
textView_title.setText(Html.fromHtml(reply_list.get(pos).getTitle()));

 AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
};
```

Comment: what is your result using this approach ?

Comment: I get the same picture as in the original post.

Comment: put white the background of the container component : list_item_reply

Answer (score 1):

i have a good magic for you

Create a layout same as custom ListView item Layout and when you **show()** your dialog box get current item and put in same layout and inflate it in dialog box

Comment: Gave this a shot, but no luck either.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide transperent theme for dialog.

add following style in values\styles.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

and provide it like ......

```
 listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_reply, R.styles.Theme.Transparent);
```

Comment: @AlexF pass activity context to adapter class and use of that.

Comment: and i just get attention you use AlertDialog. Please avoid that and use custom dialog insted of that.

Comment: I tried `listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_reply, R.style.Theme_Transparent);`, which doesn''t give me a syntax error, but get an error saying `can't resolve method inflate(int, int)`.

Comment: @AlexF I am not talking about listview. I just say change dialog method like...

`final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.splash);
dialog.show();`